# How to copy the NSString JSON in to NSDictionary?

Tags: sql-server, xcode, json, cocos2d-iphone

Actually in getting JSON data from a sql server in a encypted format and i decrypt the json data and stored in a NSString. So i have to copy the stored json string to a NSDictionary. So that i can able to call each and every data using valueForKeys.

```
NSString *requestMode = @"Hello buddy";
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://funsip.com/interaction_demo.php?requestMode=LIBRARY&categoryid=3"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[requestMode dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *err = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse* response = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err ];
if (err != nil) { NSLog(@"Failed"); }

NSString* answernew = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; `
```

so i want to copy the ansernew string to a NSDictionary.

Thanks in advance
K.Karthik

Comment: this is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775542/using-json-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

If you are targetting iOS 5.0, you can use [`NSJSONSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to parse the data:

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

You don't have to convert `data` to a string first.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) for that.